# How to run VirtualBox on OpenBSD?

Tags: virtualbox, openbsd

I'm trying to find a way to run VirtualBox on an OpenBSD host. I know there is a [port for FreeBSD](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/virtualization-host-virtualbox.html). I also know there is a [Linux compatibility layer](http://www.openbsd.org/faq/faq9.html#Interact) in OpenBSD. Would this Linux compatibility feature allow me to run the Linux version of VirtualBox on OpenBSD? Is there any other way to run VirtualBox on OpenBSD?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OpenBSD supports running (some) Linux userland programs.  It does not support running Linux kernel modules.  VirtualBox on Linux requires kernel modules (including `vboxdrv`, `vboxnetflt`, `vboxnetadp`, and `vboxpci`).

OpenBSD can not run VirtualBox as a host.  It can run as a guest VM in VirtualBox.

You need to be running Linux, FreeBSD, macOS, Solaris, or even Windows if you want to run VirtualBox as a host.

Comment: Thanks. You saved me a lot of frustration. Time to learn QEMU.

Comment: A native hypervisor is in the works, i've read. Something to be excited for - vmm(4) [@undeadly.org](http://undeadly.org/cgi?action=article&sid=20151101223132)

Comment: personally, i'd find your problem a fine excuse to switch to linux.  in particular, debian.  but that's just my subjective opinion :)

Comment: @cas I'm a big fan of Debian too; I use it most of the time. OpenBSD is mainly something to expand my horizons. I definitely think learning OpenBSD has helped me to understand Debian (and Unix-like systems) better :)

Comment: The Linux emulation support was removed in release 6.0 of OpenBSD. Nobody was using it.

Comment: Yes nobody used it because it was total buggy and emulated just a very small fraction of the advanced features. OpenBSD and NetBSD are miles behind in terms of small but usefull additions Linux has now.

Comment: @Lothar No, they’re not behind. Besides vmm is improving rapidly, and looks to become a nice solid system instead of the VMWare Fusion wannabe that is VirtualBox...

Comment: mmap with fixed address is something that will never work (Theo is against it) or what about memfd_create (now 4 years old) ?

The linux emulation is just terrible incomplete. And as desktop it will die now where Intel is joining AMD for next generation AGPU, then there will be no (opensource) graphics useable anymore for Open/Net/DragonFly BSD.

Comment: @cas: OpenBSD has some features that Linux doesn't. securelevels/pf, they're both very good and well designed.